# What is purpose of the slot at the base of my drill's handle?

Tags: tools, drill

The photo below shows a drill I own; there is a slot at the base of the handle.  Is this simply to hang things from, or does it serve another purpose?

Drill is a DeWalt model DWD210G.

[image]

Comment: Assuming this is a DWD210G, the manual makes no mention of the slot. It may be an alignment tab turned into a design feature.

Comment: @TXTurner - It is, indeed, a DWD210G; I also found no mention of it in the manual, which is why I came here.  :-)

Comment: It may be there as a security feature so the tool can be used as a demo unit. I can't think of anything else besides that though.

Comment: Yes, I suspect that's provision for a strap or lanyard.

Comment: I'm curious why you were asking... If you can get something through there, I'm sure you could use it for a lanyard/hang strap of some sort. If you were wondering where to attach the chuck key, that goes with the black rubber strap which then goes around the power cord, preferably near the plug to remind you to _unplug_ the drill _before_ removing the bit from the chuck so that you don't accidentally drill into your hand by hitting the trigger.

Answer (score 1):

The slot is for a securing strap or this Dewalt brand Drill key-Chuck keeper:

[image]

Adding some pics to show how it attaches to the drill and the chuck key:

[image]

[image]

Comment: If it's for the chuck, how does the chuck reach the hole?

Comment: You secure the chuck key keeper to the power cord, preferably near the plug to remind you to unplug the drill before releasing the bit. If you attached the keeper to the base of the handle, the chuck key would never get anywhere near close enough to the chuck to be useful.

Comment: I agree with FreeMan, its not the best place to mount the key,  plus you'd have to detach it to use it each time.  However, the OP's original question was simply what is the slot for, which this answers concisely with pics from the vendor of the product itself.  ;)

Comment: Its prob not in the documentation cause it was a stupid design, that was abandoned.  I don't think they even come with the key-keeper rubber piece  anymore...  its a pretty thin slot to get any kind of lanyard through too...

Comment: LOL just noticed the chuck key holder and rubber strap was in the OPs original picture....

Answer (score -1):

I think Tyler Durden is correct. Have a look at the [D25013K](https://servicenet.dewalt.com/Products/Detail/D25013K-B3) model; there are 4 similar holes on either side, with a separate lanyard attachment point. For what reason other than air circulation would you add such holes? Seeing that they also let contaminants in, there must be a good reason beyond good looks for placing them there (maybe the trigger switch units heat up?).

[image]

Comment: The hole does not expose the insides; if it was for ventilation, the interior would be exposed to vent hot air

Comment: @JoshDM: Look at the schematics in the link, as well as the schematics for the drill in the OP's post. Both are through holes to the inside of the handle. There is also a second hole further back missing from the OP's picture.

Answer (score -1):

It's probably to put a carry strap through

Answer (score -5):

It is for ventilation and cooling.

Comment: Citation needed?

Comment: I'd say the slots near the back of the motor body are for ventilation, but the slot at the base of the grip is probably not.